# There is some problem in how I'm extrapolating information from my chosen API

Tags: python

It works for when I call most of the muscles. But some of them don't seem to append in incremental order of 1,2,3,4,5.... They skip from 6 to 9 I think. There errors are like key error: trap6 and when I remove the traps muscle it says the same for lower_back.:
import requests
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
import re

```
    root = tk.Tk()
    tabs = ttk.Notebook(root)
    tabs.grid(row=0, column=0)
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(tab1, text = "gym")
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(tab2, text = "images")
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.add(tab3, text = "play sound")
    root["background"] = "red"
    
    # Save all info
    class Split():
      def __init__(self,name,programs):
        self.name = name
        self.programs = programs
    class Program_Routine():
      def __init__(self, name, workouts):
        self.name = name
        self.workouts = workouts
    class Workout():
      def __init__(self, name, exercises):
        self.name = name
        self.exercises = exercises
    class Exercise():
      def __init__(self,name,rep,set, diffculty,instruction,difficulty):
        self.name = name
        self.rep = rep
        self.set = set
        self.difficulty = diffculty
        self.instruction = instruction
        self.difficulty = difficulty
    def m(muscle):
      url = "https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/exercises"
      global response
      response = requests.get(f'{url}?muscle={muscle}',headers={'X-Api-Key': 'EYubhelGF0jRmCC4ZtZKZg==pWcZsqUXcpnwlFW7'})
      global request
      request = response.json()
      return request
    a = m("glutes")
    b = m("biceps")
    c = m("forearms")
    d = m("traps")
    e = m("hamstrings")
    f = m("triceps")
    g = m("calves")
    h = m("neck")
    i = m("quadriceps")
    j = m("abductors")
    k = m("abductors")
    l = m("lats")
    n = m("lower_back")
    o = m("middle_back")
    var_holder = {}
    def fill_holder(day,muscle):
      for i in day:
        var_holder[muscle + str(day.index(i))] = Exercise(i["name"], 12,3,1,i["instructions"],i["difficulty"])
    fill_holder(a,'glutes')  
    fill_holder(b,'biceps')
    fill_holder(c, 'forearms')
    fill_holder(d, 'traps')
    fill_holder(e, 'hamstrings')
    fill_holder(f,'triceps')
    fill_holder(g,'calves')
    fill_holder(h,'neck')
    fill_holder(i,'quadriceps')
    fill_holder(j,'abductors')
    fill_holder(k,'abductors')
    fill_holder(l,"lats")
    fill_holder(n,"lower_back")
    fill_holder(o,"middle_back")
    
    locals().update(var_holder)
    #print(var_holder)
    def append(indices):
      x = []
      for i in range(len(var_holder)//14):
          x.append(var_holder[f'{indices}{i}'])
      return x
    forearms = Workout("Forearm Workout", append('forearms'))
    glutes = Workout("Glutes Workout", append('glutes'))
    biceps = Workout("Bicep workout",append('biceps'))
    traps = Workout("Shoulder Workout",append('traps'))
    hamstrings = Workout("Traps workout",append('hamstrings'))
    triceps = Workout("Tricep Workout",append("triceps"))
    calves = Workout("Calves Workout",append("calves"))
    quadriceps = Workout("Traps Workout",append("quadriceps"))
    abductors1 = Workout("Traps Workout",append("abductors"))
    abductors2 = Workout("Traps Workout",append("abductors"))
    lats = Workout("Back Workout",append("lats"))
    lower_back = Workout("Back Workout",append("lower_back"))
    middle_back = Workout("Back Workout",append("middle_back"))
    
    Leg_Day = Program_Routine("Legs", [glutes,hamstrings,calves,quadriceps,abductors1,abductors2])
    Arm_Day = Program_Routine("Arms", [forearms,biceps,triceps])
    Shoulder_Day = Program_Routine("Shoulders", [traps])
    Back_Day = Program_Routine("Back",[lats,lower_back,middle_back])
    
    Five_day_split = Split("5 day split",[Leg_Day,Arm_Day,Shoulder_Day,Back_Day])
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    def display(insert):
      url = f'https://uk.images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrIfln4XytkPt4DqAAM34lQ;_ylu=Y29sbwNpcjIEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3BpdnM-?p={insert}&fr2=piv-web&type=E210GB91082G0&fr=mcafee'
      page = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
      holder = soup.find('img')
      if holder['alt'] == "":
        holder['alt'] = "Something"
      
      def Show_Image(tab,image,displayname):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, displayname) 
        #renderPM.drawToFile(svg2rlg(displayname), displayname+"png", fmt='PNG')
        global img
        img = Image.open(displayname)
        img = img.resize((250, 250))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        lbl = tk.Label(tab,image=img)
        lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
        os.remove(displayname)
      Show_Image(tab2,holder['data-src'],holder['alt'])
    
    insde_frame = tk.Frame(tab1,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
    insde_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    insde_frame.propagate(False)
    insde_frame.config(width=200,height=150)
    
    def show(program,y):
      gym = tk.StringVar()
      def clicked(value):
        name = options.index(value)
        instruct = instructions[name]
        diff = difficulty[name]
        picture = value
        if len(picture.split()) > 1:
          picture = picture.split()
          picture = '+'.join(picture)
        display(picture)
        label.config(text = instruct,wraplength = 500)
        label2.config(text = diff, wraplength = 600)
        length = 0
        for j in range(len(program.workouts)):
          length = length + len(program.workouts[j].exercises)
        label2.grid(row=length+1, column=0)
        label.grid(row=length, column=0)
      options = []
      instructions = []
      difficulty = []
      # Upload info to arrays in order to fill out radiobuttons
      for j in range(len(program.workouts)):
        for i in range(len(program.workouts[j].exercises)):
          instructions.append(program.workouts[j].exercises[i].instruction)
          difficulty.append(program.workouts[j].exercises[i].difficulty)  
          options.append(program.workouts[j].exercises[i].name)      
        for i in range(len(program.workouts[j].exercises)):
          Radio = tk.Radiobutton(insde_frame,
                                 text=program.workouts[j].exercises[i].name,
                                 variable=gym,
                                 value=program.workouts[j].exercises[i].name,
                                 command=lambda: clicked(gym.get()))
          Radio.grid(row=1+i, column=j)
      global label
      label = tk.Label(tab2 , text = "")
      label.grid(row=0, column=y+1)
      global label2
      label2 = tk.Label(tab2 , text = "")
      label2.grid(row=1, column=y+1)
      
    
    Shoulder_Day.workouts[0].exercises[4].name = "Pullup"
    Shoulder_Day.workouts[0].exercises[5].name = "Muscleup"
    del Shoulder_Day.workouts[0].exercises[1]
    del Shoulder_Day.workouts[0].exercises[3]
    
    #show(Five_day_split.programs[1],0)
    
    url = "https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/exercises"
    global response
    response = requests.get(f'{url}?type=cardio',headers={'X-Api-Key': 'EYubhelGF0jRmCC4ZtZKZg==pWcZsqUXcpnwlFW7'})
    global request
    request = response.json()
    print(request)
    
    
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(tab3)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1)
    myList = tk.Listbox(tab3, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    for line in range(1,101):
      myList.insert("end", "This is line number "+str(line))
    myList.grid(row=0,column=0)
    scrollbar.config(command=myList.yview)
    
    
    
    '''
    # It is a text value that we want to convert to audio  
    speech = 'All the best for your exam. I hope you do well!'  
    # Here are converting in English Language  
    language = 'en'  
    # Passing the text and language to the engine,  
    # here we have assign slow=False. Which denotes  
    # the module that the transformed audio should  
    # have a high speed  
    obj = gTTS(text=speech, lang=language, slow=False)  
    #Here we are saving the transformed audio in a mp3 file named  
    # exam.mp3  
    obj.save("exam.mp3")   
    # Play the exam.mp3 file 
    pygame.mixer.init()
    renderPM.drawToFile(svg2rlg(displayname), displayname+"png", fmt='PNG')
    playlist = tk.Listbox(tab3,bg="black",fg="green",width=60)
    playlist.grid(row=0,column=0)
    back_btn = tk.PhotoImage(file = "back50.jpg")
    forward_btn = tk.PhotoImage(file = "forward50.jpg")
    play_btn = tk.PhotoImage(file = "play50.jpg")
    pause_btn = tk.PhotoImage(file = "pause50.jpg")
    stop_btn = tk.PhotoImage(file = "stop50.jpg")
    '''
    
    tk.mainloop()
```

I expected it to have worked like the other functions did